# Need a very low power, low force motor/actuator

Tags: motor, servo

What are some alternative types of motors/actuators that can be used instead of servos?  I need some way of inducing a slight bit of motion/movement but with very little force and power consumption.  Even the tiniest sub-micro servos use quite a bit of current and may have quite a bit more torque than is necessary.  I thought about using muscle wire, but I need something that doesn't take up much space, and they don't appear to have shorter lengths of wire available.  Not only that, but I would prefer to have a rotary rather than a linear actuator.  What would be some options for such an actuator running at say 3v and requiring somewhere in the range of 20-40 mA of current?

Comment: Can you put some numbers to the torque, speed and distance values you need?

Comment: Does the device have to retain its' position after power is removed from the actuator?  For example, could you use a voice coil or galvanometer type actuator?  For example, galvo actuators are used in laser visual effects machines to move the mirrors that steer the laser beam.

Comment: What about hacking a battery operated clock mechanism? Low power, low voltage, cheap, available and rotary.

Comment: I was thinking a piezo, for rotary motion something like the squiggle drive/?  New focus has a piezo rotary drive.. none of those are cheap.

Comment: Pager motors. And search ebay for "small motor" etc. There are a vast number there.

Comment: Not sure how much torque needed.  The point is to touch a touchscreen tablet.  So I need just enough force in order to simulate a finger press without damaging the delicate screen.  I previously looked at a sub-micro servo with 11 ounces/inch torque, but don't know how to convert that into linear force at the end of the servo arm.  I have no idea if even this tiny servo is too powerful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the drive mechanism from my beloved [Butterfly Livingroom Flyer](http://www.microflight.com/Butterfly-Livingroom-Flyer)...
[image]

It is a pager motor connected to a reduction gear. By picking the size of the gears (or possibly adding additional gear stages), you can have pretty much any viable torque/power combination you want, down to single digits of mA.

If you need even a smaller actuator, Plantranco also sells the [MicroAct Magnetic Actuator - 0.4g](http://www.microflight.com/Online-Catalog/Actuators-and-Servos/MicroAct-Magnetic-Actuator-0-4g)...

[image]

You could also make something similar to this yourself with some very high gauge enameled wire and a small super-magnet. This would give you lots of control of the power/torque/range-of-motion trade offs.

(Note that I have no connection to Plantranco other than I have bought more of their flyers than I'd care to admit!)

I also love Jim's suggestion of hacking a clock motor if that could work for your application. These things use impossibly small amounts of current.

Here is a product that is basically a clock motor, but good for hacking because it comes with lots of possible gear combinations, and also provides continuous rotation (the yellow metal disk acts a a flywheel), whereas clock drives usually have unneeded timing circuits and often move in a a once-per-second jerk ...

[image]

They cost about [$30 on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000068UG6), much cheaper if you need more than about a dozen.